# How to hide or remove navigation Bar at the top?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

This code is successful excuted then "terms and condition page" open. But 1 problem i face extra one navigation bar show on the top of the page. how to hide or remove that navigation bar at the top of the page ?

**ClsMainPageAppDelegate.m**

```
#import "ClsMainPageAppDelegate.h"
#import "ClsTermsandConditionViewController.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ClsTermsandConditionViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"termsandConditionControl"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
    self.window.rootViewController=nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: You are showing your "terms and conditions" view controller in a navigation controller. Did you also add a navigation bar in your storyboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you read the documentation? [`UINavigationController Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Isn't this a bandaid to a bigger problem? Shouldn't the solution be to figure out why there are two nav bars?

Answer (score 4):

In your storyboard select your navigation controller. On the right in the 4th tab uncheck show navigation bar.